# 'HtmlElement' is an ambiguous reference

Tags: c#

I liked the meeting developed the use of the DOM page of a website, which took the content first in WinForms and now I am trying to implement the same thing that I feel WinForms to a WebForm in C #.

1. The page to which I am registering the DOM with C # has several IFRAME the HTML code of the Website
2. Inside the C code, it was necessary to read the content that is inside IFRAME with id = A4, Inside Iframe.
3. Within the IFRAME with the ID A4 this contains several Select nested with Ajax where, as indicated, I have problems to read.
4. The problem is the following problem of reading the selection that is inside the iframe A4 which I do in WinForm but when I try to adapt the code to the WebForm I get the following problem

> Compiler Error Message: CS0104: 'HtmlElement' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlElement' and 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement'.

My C# code is as follows:

```
private void GetLinksFromFrames()
{
    try
    {
        webPoderJudicial.Navigate("https://misitio.com/frameInv.php");
        string frameUrl;

        if (!(this.webPoderJudicial.Document == null))
        {
            //  WebCargado = true;
            HtmlWindow currentWindow = this.webPoderJudicial.Document.Window;
            if (currentWindow.Frames.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (HtmlWindow frame in currentWindow.Frames)
                {
                    frameUrl = frame.Url.ToString();
                    if (frameUrl == "https://oficinajudicialvirtual.pjud.cl/moduloautoconsulta.php")
                    {
                        HtmlElementCollection select = frame.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
                        foreach (HtmlElement el in select)
                        {
                            if (el.Name == "competencia")
                            {
                                Application.DoEvents();
                                foreach (HtmlElement ele in el.GetElementsByTagName("option"))
                                {
                                    cmbCompetencia.Items.Add(ele.InnerText);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                   
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please either translate your question into English, or post it on https://es.stackoverflow.com/ This site is only for English questions.

Comment: I'm assuming you want `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlElement` as such remove your reference `using...` to the other library. Or.. fully qualify which one you want `foreach (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlElement el in select)` for example.

Comment: Los using que tengo declarados dentro del formulario
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls; 
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;  http://subirimagen.me/uploads/20180421165339.PNG

Comment: my references http://subirimagen.me/uploads/20180422184256.PNG